# Basic calculator with "else if" method issues c++

Tags: c++

Have this simple code problems? Problem is that whenever I press B or C it is always just add no other function.

PS: Here is code

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    char choice;
    int number1, number2;
    int ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4;
    cout << "Insert first number. \n";
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Insert second number. \n";
    cin >> number2;
    cout << "Choice just one. A is for addition, B for subtraction , C for      multiplication, D for division \n";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice = 'A' )
    {ans1 = number1 + number2;
    cout << " answer is " << ans1 << endl;
     }
    else if (choice = 'B' )
    {ans2 = number1 - number2;
    cout << "Answer is" << ans2 << endl;
     }
     else if (choice = 'C')
     {ans3 = number1 * number2;
     cout << "answer is " << ans3 << endl;
     }
     else if
     (choice = 'D')
      {ans4 = number1 / number2;
      cout << "answer is" << ans4 << endl;
     }
    else
     cout << "Problem \n";




   return 0;
      }
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, use `==` to compare. `if (choice == 'A' )`, and so on...

Comment: That formatting is a tragedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your if statements you are using '=', and it should be '=='

For example:

```
if (choice = 'A')
```

Should be

```
if (choice == 'A')
```

Comment: Thank you it is working now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (choice = 'A' )
```

`=` is the assignment operator, which assigns `'A'` to `choice`.

That's probably not what you want. You probably want to compare `choice` to `'A'`. Equality comparison uses the `==` operator:

```
if (choice == 'A')
```